# Nodejs block until async calls complete?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, async.js

How would one make a nodejs application wait for async calls to finish?

main.coffee:

```
hosts = require './suhosts'
dns = require 'dns'
async = require 'async'

data = {}
async.each hosts, (host, cb_e) ->
   dns.lookup host,  (err, address, family)-> data[host] = address
 , () ->
   console.log data
```

if one runs this like `coffee main.coffee` it will exit before doing the work.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442676/how-to-prevent-node-js-from-exiting-while-waiting-for-a-callback

Comment: Normally, it would wait. What happens when you only do one lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not calling the required `async.each` callback.

```
data = {}
async.each hosts, (host, cb_e) ->
   dns.lookup host, (err, address, family) ->
      data[host] = address
      cb_e(err)
 , () ->
   console.log data
```