# node_acl seems to do literally nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, acl

I have been trying to integrate [this acl package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl) but I can't get it to do anything - even throw errors.  I've distilled it down about as simple as I can get and this is basically exactly from the example in their documentation:

```
import * as nodeAcl from 'acl';

...(DB initialization and other stuff happens here)...

acl = new nodeAcl(new nodeAcl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db, "acl_"));

debug("Testing ACL...");

acl.allow('guest', 'blogs', 'view');
acl.addUserRoles('joe', 'guest');
acl.isAllowed('joe', 'blogs', 'view', function(err, res){
    if(res){
        debug("User joe is allowed to view blogs")
    }
    debug("Callback was called...");
});

debug("done testing acl");
```

I just get "Testing ACL..." and "done testing acl" to my debug output and that's it.  No errors, nothing written to the DB (which is working fine - I can write/read with it).  Just nothing happens.  Even an error would be welcome.

Comment: Seems like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442676/how-to-prevent-node-js-from-exiting-while-waiting-for-a-callback

Comment: I don't see how they are related - this is about an access control package, that link talks about a problem with node itself. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems like node is finishing before your callback is called.

Comment: No - there's a whole project running around this code that works fine and stays up indefinitely.  This was being added to an existing express app.  From reading the acl github issues page it seems that mongodb support is questionable.

Comment: Ah, ok. That wasn't clear (to me) from the original question. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I could see how that would be unclear.  Sorry.