# Node exits without error and doesn't await promise (Event callback)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've got a really weird issue whereby awaiting a Promise that has passed its `resolve` to an event-emitter callback just exits the process without error.

```
const {EventEmitter} = require('events');

async function main() {
  console.log("entry");

  let ev = new EventEmitter();

  let task =  new Promise(resolve=>{
    ev.once("next", function(){resolve()}); console.log("added listener");
  });

  await task;

  console.log("exit");
}

main()
.then(()=>console.log("exit"))
.catch(console.log);

process.on("uncaughtException", (e)=>console.log(e));
```

I'm expecting the process to halt when I run this because clearly "next" is currently never emitted. but the output I get is:

> entry 
>   added listener

and then the nodejs process terminates gracefully.

I thought it was something to do with the Garbage Collector, but `ev` and `task` are clearly still in scope on `main`. So I'm really at a loss as to why the process exits entirely without error.

Obviously I *would* eventually emit the event, but I've simplified my code to the above to reproduce. I'm on `node v8.7.0`. Is there something wrong with my code or is this a node bug?

Comment: hmm I suspect the answer is that once all the callbacks are setup, and while technically all correct, there is _no code running_ any more.

Comment: What does "*just completely bombs out*" mean? What is the difference between "*process halts*" (what you were expecting) and "*the process exits entirely without error*"?

Comment: cleared that up; it _is_ exiting gracefully. I'm pretty sure the answer to this is that there simply is nothing running and no system events/files open so node considers the program complete.

Comment: So by "halt" you mean "hang without exiting"?

Comment: Yes, just creating a never-resolved promise (like the call `main()` does) doesn't keep node from exiting - it's just garbage-collected. There would need to be a live global callback, like a `setTimeout`, that still references the promise and *could* resolve it (but never does).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This question is basically: how does node decide whether to exit the event loop or go around again?

Basically node keeps a reference count of scheduled async requests — `setTimeouts`, network requests, etc.. Each time one is scheduled, that count increases, and each time one is finished, the count decreases. If you arrive at the end of an event loop cycle and that reference count is zero node exits.

Simply creating a promise or event emitter does *not* increase the reference count — creating these objects isn't actually an async operation. For example, this promise's state will always be pending but the process exits right away:

```
const p = new Promise( resolve => {
    if(false) resolve()
})

p.then(console.log)
```

In the same vein this also exits after creating the emitter and registering a listener:

```
const ev = new EventEmitter()
ev.on("event", (e) => console.log("event:", e))
```

If you expect Node to wait on an event that is never scheduled, then you may be working under the idea that Node doesn't know whether there are future events possible, but it does because it keeps a count every time one is scheduled.

So consider this small alteration:

```
const ev = new EventEmitter()
ev.on("event", (e) => console.log("event:", e))

const timer = setTimeout(() => ev.emit("event", "fired!"), 1000)
// ref count is not zero, event loop will go again. 
// after timer fires ref count goes back to zero and node exits
```

As a side note, you can remove the reference to the timer with: `timeout.unref()`. This, unlike the previous example, will exit immediately:

```
const ev = new EventEmitter()
ev.on("event", (e) => console.log("event:", e))

const timer = setTimeout(() => ev.emit("event", "fired!"), 1000)
timer.unref()
```

There's a good talk about the event loop by Bert Belder here that clears up a lot of misconceptions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNa9OMajw9w

Comment: @ Mark Meyer - very useful answer here, thanks, makes the whole issue very clear. Regarding this: `Basically node keeps a reference count of scheduled async requests. setTimeouts, network requests, etc` -- do you know if there's a strict definition of what this includes? Is it basically anything async from node's core/native modules?

Comment: Can you make your first example (the Promise example) wait?

Comment: @SohailSi, you can add a setTimeout that resolves the promise in the first example. Then it will wait for the amount of time the timer is set.

Comment: Great answer. Do you have insight into how this plays out in the browsers? e.g. v8? Or all the times you references to node in your text (e.g. node keeps a reference count, node exits, etc), it can be also interpreted as v8 (e.g. v8 keeps a reference count, v8 exits, etc)? so things would work in the exact same way in browser too.

Comment: @Gaurang Patel - Does a browser javascript engine ever even exit?  (I think not.)

Answer (score 3):

I was debugging for several hours why one of our scripts exits (without any errors) after one line of code in the middle of `main` function. It was a line `await connectToDatabase(config)`. And you know what?

I found that difference between these two functions is CRUCIAL:

first:

```
async function connectToDatabase(config = {}) {
    if (!config.port) return;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       resolve();
    })
}
```

second:

```
async function connectToDatabase(config = {}) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       if (!config.port) return;
       resolve();
    })
}
```

second function sometimes (when config.port is empty) creates never-resolved promise, it makes event loop empty, and node.js exits thinking that "nothing more to do here"

check it yourself:

```
// index.js - start it as node index.js
(async function main() {
  console.log('STARTED')
  await connectToDatabase()
  console.log('CONNECTED')
  console.log('DOING SOMETHING ELSE')
})()
```

'CONNECTED' and 'DOING SOMETHING ELSE' are NOT printed if you use second function and are printed, if you use first

Comment: on the second, if `config.port` is undefined then your promise will never resolve, ever... because you're not calling either resolve, or reject. the callback `(reject, resolve)=>{}` should be sync though - and if you raise a socket request in there, it should keep node alive.

Answer (score -3):

As a general note, your code is combining three similar, but different methods: async/await, promises, event listeners. I'm not sure what you mean by "bombs out." But looking at the code, the result seems expected.

Your process exits, because you called promise on adding your event listener. It successfully resolves, and therefore exits. If you try to log task, it will give you undefined. Instead of logging "exit" in your then statement, log the result. Task will be undefined since the program does not wait to resolve its value and its "code block has finished".

You can simplify your code to the following. As you can see it resolves immediately since you call the resolve function.

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');

let ev = new EventEmitter()
var p = new Promise(( resolve ) => {
    ev.once("next", resolve("Added Event Listener"));
})

p
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: Your code is not semantically identical to OP's; your Promise is resolving because you haven't put the `resolve` call in a function, so it is being evaluated immediately.

Comment: That was the idea. He was confused about why it was working  as it was so I wrote it another way to show it. There's nothing to "solve" apart from the understanding.

Comment: I'm afraid it will never _resolve_ because the event is never emitted. The example is contrived and ultimately, it boils down to what Mark's answer states.

Comment: I understand that. I was trying to show that without an emit or setTimeout that the resolve (even nested) will not stop your program from halting. But in any case, Mark's answer is clearer.

Comment: I am afraid that the gist of my answer was lost in its obscurity.  Both of you are correct. It is contrived. I was trying to show that (borrowing Marks answer) `a promise or event emitter does not increase the reference count` regardless of how that promise is implemented.

Comment: Well, my example was contrived (wasn't having a go) - I'm actually doing stream -> async iterable conversion (that's why I'm mixing the three). I guess you were talking about the function returning when you say "resolved", but in the context of a promise "resolve" is when the promise completes. That why your answer seems to be wrong at first glance.

Comment: Your code don't use event emitter, that's why it's wrong. It's the same as `new Promise(resolve => resolve('Added Event Listener'));`. The event emitter in your code only confuse the reader. That's why you got a down vote.