# Why is Node exiting with exit code 13, rather than hanging?

Tags: node.js, async-await

A file `deadlock.mjs` with this in it:

```js
await new Promise(function(resolve) {});
```

will run and immediately end giving an exit code of 13. I would've expected this program to hang forever.

```js
await new Promise(function(resolve) {resolve()});
```

unsurprisingly ends immediately and gives a 0 exit code.

Why doesn't the first program deadlock? And what is the significance of exit code 13?

Comment: Unresolved promises by themselves do NOT keep nodejs from exiting.  nodejs waits for sockets, files, timers, etc... but does not wait for a promise all by itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Node isn't deadlocking because it's noticing that it's not waiting on anything. [Here's a great explanation of how it notices that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46916601/3920202). But because you've used a top-level await here, Node knows that it's exiting abnormally and gives a 13 exit code:

> `13` **Unfinished Top-Level Await**: `await` was used outside of a function in the top-level code, but the passed `Promise` never resolved.

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#exit-codes

Comment: I didn't dive deeply into why 13 is the exit code, rather than 1 (which is what node normally uses when the program dies due to an error). But the weird exit code is the main reason I made this question: 13 isn't mentioned _anywhere_ that I could find. So I'm making this a community wiki because hopefully someone will be able to share more.

Comment: In my case, I oddly had to explicitly exit with `process.exit(0)` (with a top-level `await`; on Node 14.15.5), I'm guessing because the `await` situation was setting `process.exitCode` (which can override the default of `0`).

Comment: Updated the answer with the docs on exit code 13.