# Writing to file in NodeJS calling from another JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a weird issue writing to a file in NodeJS.

I have this code in my FileHandler.js:

```
module.exports.writeFile = function (arr) {
    var fs = require('fs');

    console.log(arr);
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+'\\test.txt',{encoding: 'utf8'});
    file.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);  });

    file.on("finish", function() {
        console.log("finished");
    });

    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        file.write(item+"\n");
    });

    file.end();
}
```

If I append

```
exports.writeFile(["1","2","3"])
```

To the end of this file and then run `node FileHandler.js`
The file is created correctly.

However, if I call the `writeFile` function from another .js file as:

```
var R = require("r-script");
const dataHandler = require("./DataHandler");
const fileHandler = require("./FileHandler");

var out = R(__dirname + "\\apriori.R");

exports.getRules = function () {
    dataHandler.getListOfPageVisitsBySession(1000781912582,1530781912582,function (result){
        //ignored result variable
        fileHandler.writeFile(["1","2","3"]);
    })
}
```

and passing the exact same array to the function it doesn't write anything (but the file is created), neither fires `err` or `finish` event.
If it matters, the DataHandler method contains a `request` module and a GET to another API.

Any clue of the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you import that from another file can you show that also?

Comment: Added to the main post.

Comment: Didn't you get any error?

Comment: Did you check if the callback from `getListOfPageVisitsBySession` is running ? Try log something before you call writeFile function.

Comment: I just added a log before the call to writeFile and in the first line of writeFile. They both get logged.

Comment: Im not sure but shouldnt you call file.end the on finish event ?

Comment: Just throwing ideas here, but what OS is this? Check if you have a test.txt at your root (c:\? ) :p

Comment: Windows 10. The file is created, it just stays empty. (Added this info to the main post). And, unfortunately no :(

Comment: And if you do a `setTimeout(function(){console.log("done");},10000)` last? just to check if node is quitting before it gets to write anything.

Comment: That was indeed the problem!! Node was quitting before writing to the file. Thank you!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442676/how-to-prevent-node-js-from-exiting-while-waiting-for-a-callback