# Why does a method called as a callback in response to a SIGINT signal not completely finish before process termination?

Tags: node.js, server

I am attempting to create a way to gracefully shutdown my server, but it does not seem that the method being called in response to a SIGINT is completely finishing.

I have added a callback function to the SIGINT signal using `process.on('SIGINT', cb)`

```js
var stop = () => {
  console.log("stopping server");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    server.close(() => { console.log("server closed"); resolve(); }))
    .then(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => { console.log("time out finished"); resolve(); }, 5000)))
    .then(() => process.exit(0));
}

process.on("SIGINT", stop);
```

I added the setTimeout in there just as a test to see if the server is waiting before completely shutting down.

When I send SIGINT to the process, the output I get is

`stopping server`

On a few occasions both the stopping server and the server closed logs come through, but not all the time.

I have tried implementing the wait function from this previous question: [How to prevent Node.js from exiting while waiting for a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442676/how-to-prevent-node-js-from-exiting-while-waiting-for-a-callback), but I still achieve the same results as above.

Does anyone know a workaround that will allow this method to completely finish before the server exits?

Answer (score 0):

I was having real trouble with this and using neither promises nor callbacks seemed to work.
For myself, I think the process queue emptied (and node exited) before my winston logger would save all info to files.

In any case, I eventually got around to solving it by putting in manual flags for each process I wanted to exit to return true once done. The exit itself was in an 100ms interval and would only exit on all flags true.

e.g.

```
process.on('SIGINT', exit);

function exit(){
    var myProcessFlag = myProcess.close()    //returns true once complete

    setInterval(function(){
        if(myProcessFlag == true){
            console.log('successful exit');
            process.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            console.log(`awaiting...
                         myProcess complete: ${myProcessFlag}`);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```