# Node.js stops in the middle of executing

Tags: node.js, request

I have the following code:

```
const request = require("request");

const data = {
    "url": "http://example.net/",
    "lenght": "(30 * 1000)"
};

(async () => {

    const r = request.get(data.url);

    let chank = 0;
    r.on("data", (data) => {
        chank += data.length;
        console.log("data", Math.round(chank / 1024), "kb");
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        r.abort();
    }, eval(data.lenght));

    const token = await get_token();

    let o = {
        formData: {
            file: {
                value: r,
                options: {
                    filename: "d",
                    contentType: "audio/mpeg"
                }
            },

            token: token
        },
        json: true
    };

    const u = await new Promise((resolve) => { // <----
        request.post("https://www.other.co.il/api/UploadFile", o, (err, res, body) => {
            resolve(body);
        });
    });

    console.log(u);


})();
```

The code downloads the file from Server A, and uploads it streaming to Server B. After some time, the download from Server A aborts, and Server B is supposed to return a response.

The problem:
The code is seemingly ok, but what usually happens, the node.js stops (at the line marked with a arrow), without informing an error.

The following line is never executed.
`console.log(u);`

The question is, what is wrong?

edit: This probably has to do with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636001/12054906

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing everything pretty much right, the question is, do you expect a body? If so, try logging out the body by not assigning the variable but rather logging the `await new Promise` bit. It shouldn't change the response, but if it does, your Promise is not grabbing that `resolve`. TLDR: you're probably just not getting a response from the other server. If you expect one, check the code on the server. A great way of sending requests without code would be to use a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). That could be helpful with debugging as well.

Comment: And you made sure that you're getting a response from server b?

Comment: Yes, he must return.